# Mediaplayer does not free media for taglib

Tags: c#, media-player

This is my code:

```
oldMP3 = this.MediaPlayer.URL; 
this.MediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop();
this.MediaPlayer.URL = (String)mp3List.SelectedItem;
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(oldMP3);
tagFile.Tag.Genres[0] = this.genreConcatenated.Text;
tagFile.Save();
```

When i try to save the mp3, i get an io-Exception, that the file can´t be written. How do i free the media from the mediaplayer? Doesn´t the media player free the media itself? Or what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution:

```
private void waitlUntilFileIsWritable(string fileLocation)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 100))
                {
                    //the file is close
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                //wait and retry
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not very nice, but so far i have not found anything better. Regarding to a few posts, there seems to be no other way to see, if a file is writable or not. It works now, even everything is a little to slow :/